# Статическая переменная "равняется" 0 в методе?

Tags: java, android, static

Имеются два поля:

```
private static int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
```

В методе onCreate (при переходе из другой активности) они инициализируются нормально.

```
x1 = intent.getIntExtra("x1", 0);  // значение 100 например
x2 = intent.getIntExtra("x2", 0); // значение 200
```

Затем мне необходимо совершить вычисления в методе calculateCoords

```
    Log.d("[SPECTRAL]", " x1: " + x1 + " x2:" + x2); // выводит корректно 100 200
    double temp_x_1 = x1 * (720/1080); // пишет, что все выражение может быть заменено нулем ?? (т.к. x1 = 0)
    double temp_x_2 = x2 * (720/1080); // аналогично
```

Объясните, почему так? И как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: зачем они статические?

Comment: @pavlofff, они используются в статическом методе, а сам метод статический потому что его вызывает другой статический метод

Comment: если я верно понял, то `720/1080` вот это целочисленное деление даёт всегда `0`, а если ноль умножить на что нибудь, получим ноль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант будет работать правильно:

```
double temp_x_1 = x1 * (720.0/1080);
```

В том месте, где берутся 720 и 1080, нужно превращать их в double. А если у вас в коде прямо так и написано `720/1080`, то просто замените на `0.6666666666`. Но вообще не рекомендуется использовать в коде числа, [которые непонятно откуда берутся и что означают](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: почему бы просто `720.0/1080` не хранить в какой нить константе? типа static final или как там в джаве :)

Comment: @tym32167 Ну я же примерно так и написал :)

Comment: спасибо большое!